# Regex: all ASCII characters but a certain character (PHP, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP)

Tags: php, regex, filter

Found the following nice regex to match all printable ASCII characters:

```
[ -~]
```

My code looks like this:

```
    $string = "My ASCII string is (not) very funny.";

    filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
    array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[ -~]*$/")));
```

Thats almost what I need however I want to exclude the colon. I have tried `[ -~\:]` and `[ -~^:]` which does not work. What is the correct regex and how to exclude single characters correctly?

Comment: Your string doesn't have `;` or `:` in it. A `:` is a colon, `;` is a semicolon. Which do you want to allow? What about `[[:ascii:]]`? (I haven't used regexs with `filter_var` before either, I stick with `preg_` functions usually.)

Comment: @chris: Yes right I meant a colon sorry.

Comment: Let I have sure I understand what you want. You want validate as false if you has any colon (:) or any non ascii char, don't you?

Comment: Want validate to false if I have any colon or any non-printable ASCII char or any other char. Nicael already has answered correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like that you're looking for a regex like this:

```
(?=[ -~])[^:]
```

You can exclude also the semicolon by adding it to the "exclude list" :

```
(?=[ -~])[^:;]
```

Comment: Ok correct. I was checked some solutions on google however this seems the correct way to exclude. I ended up like this: ^((?=[ -~])[^:])*$

Comment: It is not efficient though. You could just specify 2 ranges: [`^[ -9;-~]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/kN1aE6/1) (see [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)).

Comment: @stribizhev: In my case efficiency does not matter however thx for pointing out